# Can't connect to FTP Server since switching to a Pixel 8 Pro

Tags: google-pixel, ftp

I have been using the app "FTP Server" for many years. Recently I have become unable to connect to it, since switching from a Pixel 6 Pro to a Pixel 8 Pro.

I always get a "connection refused" error. I have tried connecting with Telnet, and get the same response. I can ping the phone without issue.

I also tried the "primitive FTPd" app from Play/F-Droid.

FTP Server app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.ftpserver
primitive FTPd: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.primftpd

Is something different about networking on the Pixel 8? Or in Android 14?

Edit: For reasons unknown, the next day, without rebooting the phone or anything like that, both "FTP Server" and "primitive FTPd" have started working. Perhaps it was a temporary issue, perhaps something else. I will report back if I make any progress on determining what circumstances cause this.

Comment: The "FTP Server" app is outdated and isn't available in Play Store on recent devices. Android 14 blocks very old apps: `starting with Android 14, apps with a targetSdkVersion lower than 23 can't be installed.` (23 = Android 6). But as you could install the app this doesn't seem to be the problem. May be other compatibility settings with old Android versions have been removed?

Comment: @Robert possibly, but "primitive FTPd" is current and doesn't work either. Do you know of any up to date FTP server apps that might work? Because MTP is broken on Windows.